# how can I use a debugger while running python script with pwn module on linux

Tags: linux, security

I have got a file in my linux system.
I created a python script that have some pwn methods to interact with it
Something like this:

```
from pwn import *
import sys

def main():
           io = process("../../challenges/solveit")
            io.recvline()
            payload=b'A'*20

            io.sendline(payload)
            io.interactive()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I wanna check the address value while running the py program, just like calling x/20wx $ebp-0x40 in gdb. How can I do that?

I am new to linux and just learned about gdb debugger . Can anyone explain how I can check address value while running a exploit script?
Can the gdb be used together with pwn?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `gdb.attach` method

> `pwnlib.gdb.attach(target, gdbscript='', exe=None, gdb_args=None, ssh=None, sysroot=None, api=False)`
>
> Start GDB in a new terminal and attach to target.

See the document: https://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/gdb.html#pwnlib.gdb.attach

For your code, just add a line `gdb.attach(io)`

```
@@ -7,6 +7,7 @@ def main():
     io.recvline()
     payload=b'A'*20
 
+    gdb.attach(io)
     io.sendline(payload)
     io.interactive()
```

Also, you might get error like

```
[ERROR] Could not find a terminal binary to use. Set context.terminal to your terminal.
```

This is because you haven't set a terminal for pwntools to start gdb. Just add `context.terminal = <your favorite terminal>` after you imported pwntools, like

```py
from pwn import *
context.terminal = 'kitty'
```

or

```py
import pwn
pwn.context.terminal = 'kitty'
```